# How do I build a recursive insert method into a sorted list in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, insert

The code given for the iterative version is

```
public void insert(E data) {
        Node<E> temp = new Node<E>(data);

        if (head == null || data.compareTo(head.data) < 0) {
            temp.next = head;
            head = temp;
        } else{
            Node<E> curr = head;
            while (curr.next != null && data.compareTo(curr.next.data) >=
                    0) {
                curr = curr.next;
            }
            temp.next = curr.next;
            curr.next = temp;
        }
```

Which makes enough sense to me, but I'm for some reason struggling to wrap my head around how to correctly implement it recursively.

My basic, not even psuedocode idea is have the base cases be "If the list is empty, the element is inserted at the head. If the element is less than the next node's value, insert it as the current node's next value." and then the recursion call is just to run it again at the next node. However, given that the main method, which we are not supposed to change, only takes the one parameter, I'm not sure what to do. I had hoped that since the slides we were taught about linked list seemed to imply the `curr` reference variable was always around, that this could be used. Something along the lines of iterating that in the case neither base case was fulfilled. However, A) that has not been working when I've tried it, and B) that would make it so that the method would not work correctly beyond its first call, since returning `curr` to the head within the method would happen each time its called recursively. I am at a loss right now and could really use help. I've even attempted googling this problem to no avail, with solutions that either use multiple parameters and ones that ignore the fact the list is supposed to stay sorted. Thanks in advance for any help you'd be able to provide!

Comment: You need to write another private helper method which takes two parameters. The public method calls it, then it calls itself.

Answer (score 1):

> given that the main method, which we are not supposed to change, only takes the one parameter, I'm not sure what to do.

The way out of this paradox is to create a second method. This method can take the extra node argument, and can be private as only the existing method will use it. It can *return* the node that would be the head if this was the first call, but it is up to the caller to do with it what is needed: either assign it to `head` or assign it to the preceding node's `next` attribute.

So:

```
    private Node<E> insert(Node<E> first, E data) {
        if (first == null || data.compareTo(first.data) < 0) {
            Node<E> temp = new Node<E>(data);
            temp.next = first;
            return temp;
        }
        first.next = insert(first.next, data);
        return first;
    }
    
    public void insert(E data) {
        head = insert(head, data);
    }
```